# Delphi component creation design time

Tags: delphi

So far, to make things easy, I have always created components that are Desingtime and Runtime and I've used the component wizard. It works fine but I see that separating runtime and designtime is better.

[image]

The `Frazioni.bpl` is a Runtine only package and it has in Contains a pas file called `uFraction.pas`. It is an utility for fractions and it has inside a class like this:

```
type
 TFraction = class(TComponent)
 end;
```

dclFrazioni instead is Designtime only. I am reading More Coding in Delphi and nick says:

> First thing to do for a design-time package is to set its Requires
>   clause

Ok but how do I do this? I understand that I have to link the runtime and the Designtime but how? I have built the Frazioni.bpl but when I right click dclFrazioni I have to add a reference but I don't know how.

The designtime only package is just going to have the `Register` procedure. So basically:

- Frazioni.bpl = runtime with one (or more) pas file containing the classes I need, they inherit from TComponent.
- dclFrazioni.bpl = designtime with a pas file containing the Register procedure

I am lost because I don't know how to link them.

Comment: This should not be a component that you drop onto a design surface.

Comment: You need separate runtime and designtime packages only when you have actual designtime-only code, such as component/property editors, IDE addons, etc.  It is perfectly fine to have a single runtime+designtime package if it does not contain any designtime-only code in it (and simply calling `RegisterComponents()` doesn't count, as it is implemented in a runtime package).

Comment: You could simply compile and build the runtime, right click the dcl, click "Add Reference" and then go to "C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\xx.x\Dcp".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can link your designtime package to your runtime package by adding the name of the runtime package to the `requires` section of the designtime package's project file.

You can do that by following these steps:

1. Right click on `dclFrazioni.bpl`
2. Click `View Source` from the `Project Manager` window.
3. Add `Frazioni` (Which is your runtime package) to the `requires` section.

The resulting file should looks like the following:

```
package dclFrazioni;

{$R *.res}
....
{$IMPLICITBUILD OFF}

requires
  rtl,
  vcl,
  Frazioni;

contains
  (units...);

end.
```

Answer (score 3):

In your screenshot it lists the tree view item called Requires for your design package. IIRC you can right click that and choose Add Reference. Then select your run-time package.

Comment: I had already done that but I cannot find any bpl file to add

Comment: Your recollection is correct. This achieves the same with the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45719698) without having to modify project source directly.

Comment: Does it compile? Otherwise there will be no DCP file at all.
Then you can find the DCP  file around `C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\11.0\Dcp` ?